# Place elements side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a push animation, where one element 'pushes' the other.

I have 4 `divs` in a parent `div` 2 are boxes that I want the push animation happening on, and 2 'button' `divs`. The wrapper `div` doesn't have a set height.

The problem is, the second box `div` gets placed under the first box `div`. How can I get them to be right and left of each other, not one on top of the other.

Also, I need a bit of help with the animation. How can I get one box `div` to 'push' the other?

This is what I mean by 'push' effect:

[image]

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('#leftBtn').click(function() {
    $('#leftBox').animate({
      left: '-200px'
    });
    $('#rightBox').animate({
      left: '-200px'
    });
  });

  $('#rightBtn').click(function() {
    $('#leftBox').animate({
      left: '200px'
    });
    $('#rightBox').animate({
      left: '200px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#leftBox,
#rightBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#rightBox {
  left: 400px;
}
#leftBtn,
#rightBtn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftBox" style="background-color: cornflowerblue;">Hello
    </div><div id="rightBox" style="background-color: darkkhaki;">Bye Bye
    </div><div id="leftBtn" style="background-color: yellowgreen;">Click Me
    </div><div id="rightBtn" style="background-color: yellow;">No, Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want the boxes to "push" each other? Please describe this functionality in more detail.

Comment: Updated question with example

Comment: The concept is not push. You have to align the divs side by side and this will be inside another parent div. Now you need to move the parent div left or right depending upon the width of each div. Got it?

Comment: Hey there. Why don't you use a very wide html element instead of attempting to use `display: inline-block;`? You could then easily animate it by translating it over the X axis. Here is an example of an old question I asked, which was answered to me pretty neatly: http://goo.gl/Z9WaMH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` on `#leftBox` & `#rightBox` to place them side by side. For animation, wrap them with another `div(#wrapper)` & change the position of `#wrapper` on click .

**Example:**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzgb84vz/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="leftBox" style="background-color: cornflowerblue;">Hello
    </div>
    <div id="rightBox" style="background-color: darkkhaki;">Bye Bye
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="buttons">
    <div id="leftBtn" style="background-color: yellowgreen;">Click Me
    </div>
    <div id="rightBtn" style="background-color: yellow;">No, Click Me!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    $('#leftBtn').click(function() {
        $('#slider').animate({
            left: '-400px'
        });
    });

    $('#rightBtn').click(function() {
        $('#slider').animate({
            left: '0px'
        });
    });
});
```