# Create a push animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a push animation, where one element 'pushes' the other. Something like this:

[image]

I finally got it implemented, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34196530/5244870). But now I have another problem. I want `#slider`, `leftBox`, and `rightBox` to have a height based on its content. I don't want to set a fixed height to it.

If I remove their heights, and because their heights will be based on its content, I cannot assign a fixed `margin-top` to `#buttons`, so I will also have to remove `margin` for `#buttons`. Now that I had to remove all that, the `#slider` is hidden.

Also, I don't want `#buttons` in `#wrapper`, I want it in its own `div` places elsewhere.

How can I have a push animation like the above GIF, with the height being dynamic?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('#leftBtn').click(function() {
    $('#slider').animate({
      left: '-400px'
    });
  });

  $('#rightBtn').click(function() {
    $('#slider').animate({
      left: '0px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#leftBox,
#rightBox {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
#rightBox {
  left: 400px;
}
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
}
#buttons {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="leftBox" style="background-color: cornflowerblue;">Hello
    </div>
    <div id="rightBox" style="background-color: darkkhaki;">Bye Bye
      <br/>See you
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <div id="leftBtn" style="background-color: yellowgreen;">Click Me
  </div>
  <div id="rightBtn" style="background-color: yellow;">No, Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure i managed to get what you want.
I have two JSFiddles for you, the first one is supported by all (decent) browsers, while the second one probably fits what you want better but is only supported in all browsers except for internet explorer.

The first one: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmxe5cx/

```
#leftBox,
#rightBox {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#slider {
  width: 800px;
}
```

The boxes do not fill the container completely height-wise but as i said this should have wider support.

The second one: http://jsfiddle.net/hr8nzde8/

```
#leftBox,
#rightBox {
  width: 400px;
}

#slider {
  width: 800px;
  display:flex;
}
```

The boxes do fill the containers completely in this version, this should also just generally cause less trouble if you decide to change some CSS for the boxes themselves